# Phone calls immediately hang up - unless headphones are connected

Tags: iphone, ios, software-update, call

Since updating to iOS 14.3 on my iPhone 7, incoming and outgoing phone calls immediately hang up with the error message below unless I have any Bluetooth headset connected.

[image: Call Failed]

Everything works fine with a headset, though. As doing phone calls is kind of an important functionality in an um... phone,  I would love to be able to restore the phone call feature.

What would be steps to try to fix this problem?

Comment: I'm assuming you already rebooted your device.  You can also try taking the SIM out and reinserting it.  You can also try [these troubleshooting steps](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204027) to see if they help.

Comment: @fsb thanks for the input, the steps didn't really change anything. 

When I do an outgoing call, the call is technically working (it's ringing at the other end, _and_ I hear the beeping of the call being made), but the second the call gets connected, the error occurs.

Comment: I know you said it was working with a headset.  Do you have another iPhone you can put your SIM in to check?  If it works then it's probably a hardware issue (mic, I'm thinking).  If you can go to your carrier's local store, they probably have a test device you can use.

Comment: As a (former) iPhone 7 user with a similar problem, I presume you are also unable to record voice memos or audio in your videos. If so, I am afraid it is a common problem having to do with the sound card of your iPhone: https://www.consumeraffairs.com/news/apple-iphone-7-owners-report-sound-issue-011519.html Apple has previously offered cheap(er) repairs for this issue, but I am unaware if this is still the case.

Comment: Note that if you do not occur sound issues in other areas, please let us know! Then it might be a software issue.

Comment: @appelflapper indeed, voice memos and things like e.g. WhatsApp voice messages also do not work. This is a good hint. Maybe you can convert it into an answer and I'm happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a (former) iPhone 7 user with a similar problem, I presume you are also unable to record voice memos or audio in your videos. If so, I am afraid it is a common problem having to do with the sound card of your iPhone 7: https://www.consumeraffairs.com/news/apple-iphone-7-owners-report-sound-issue-011519.html Apple has previously offered cheap(er) repairs for this issue, but I am unaware if this is still the case. Be sure to contact your local Apple dealer to see if this is the case.

Otherwise, there are second-party shops which should be able to perform this repair. Your iPhone is most likely already out of warranty so there should not be significant issues with future repairs. However, Apple has previously said they will not repair items repaired outside of official Apple shops, so it might be wise to do some further research and decide if you are willing to take the risk.